# Unable to DISABLE button when quanitity is zero in Vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, shopify

I am trying to use vue to increase and decrease input values on a quantity selector component, the only issue is when the value is zero or lower i want to disable the minus button, below is the HTML and JS i have created so far, the alert and the updateButtonDisabled() function are not working.

The HTML with click functions

```
<div class="input-group-prepend">
  <span id="subButton" class="input-group-text" @click="decrement()">-</span>
</div>

<input v-model="form.quantity" type="number" class="form-control" id="Quantity" value="1" min="1" {% if product.variants.size == 1 %}max="{{ product.variants.first.inventory_quantity}}"{% endif %}>

<div class="input-group-append">
  <span class="input-group-text" @click="increment()">+</span>
</div>
```

The JS and data

```
    data(){
      return {
        form: {
          id: document.getElementById('variant-id').value,
          quantity: document.getElementById('Quantity').value
        }
      }
    }

      updateButtonDisabled(){
        // If quanitity less than equal zero disable the minus button
        if(this.form.quantity <= 0) {
          document.getElementById("subButton").setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
        else {
          document.getElementById("subButton").removeAttribute('disabled');
        }
      },
      increment () {
        this.form.quantity++
        this.updateButtonDisabled();

      },
      decrement () {
        if(this.form.quantity <= 0) {
          alert('Negative quantity not allowed')
        } else {
          this.form.quantity--
        }
         this.updateButtonDisabled();
      }
```

Any help would be great - thanks

Answer (score 2):

A `<span>` doesn't react to having a `disabled` attribute.

You have two options: use a DOM element which, natively (or in whatever framework you use) changes appearance when `disabled` attribute is present. Such as `<button>`.

Or, you could simply apply a class (how about `disabled`?) to the element and style it to your heart's content:

```
 span.disabled { 
   opacity: 0.5;
   pointer-events: none;
 }
```

One more note: don't manipulate DOM in your component like that. Vue can do it for you, as simple as:

```
<button :disabled="form.quantity <= 0">
```

Or, using a class:

```
<span :class="{ disabled: form.quantity <= 0}">
```

I wouldn't call doing it yourself wrong, but it reminds me of a guy pushing a sports car down the road instead of driving it.

Final note: no need to call `updateButtonDisabled()` anymore. That's the beauty of using Vue. It's reactive.